# Problem with Caspr antibody in western blotting

Tags: western-blot

I have been working on optimizing western blotting for Caspr (contactin associated protein), but I am having difficulties and would like suggestions.

1. I ran my proteins on a 40% acrylamide gel,
2. I used TBST for washing and BSA as blocking buffer.
3. I incubated the blot with primary antibody overnight.
4. The secondary antibody is linked with HRP.

I could  not find any bands in the blot.(Same problem was faced in case of contactin) What might be the reason?

Edit:-

- I repeated the experiment a couple of times and found that secondary antibody(Anti-mouse,1:5000)wasn't working anymore.
- I made freshly diluted secondary antibody again and found bands.
- The old secondary antibody dilution was only few months old.What may have gone wrong with it?

[image: blot images]

Comment: What percentage is your gel? And: Did you do Ponceau staining of the membrane?

Comment: The resolving gel was 8%. Yes, Ponceau staining was done.

Comment: And there you did see bands I assume. How old is your antibody dilution?

Comment: Do you have a positive control (actin or something)?

Comment: Usually you visualize the bands on the blot by exposing the blot to X-ray film or otherwise visualizing the HRP reaction, because you can't just see the reaction on the blot. Can you show us a film or other exposure of the blot? The blot itself looks ok but it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing such an exposure.

Comment: There were bands in ponceau staining. The antibodies are 2-3 months old.